# Conditional Property After Powershell Left Join

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, properties

When I do a left join on two objects via Powershell I define a property 'Name'. I want the property to have the value of the 'Name' field in the right object if the record exists and the value of the 'Name' field in the left object if it does not.

I have tried various conditional statements like

```
@{ Name = If($Right.Length -eq 0){'Left.Name'}else{'Right.Name'}}
@{ Name = If($Right -eq $null){'Left.Name'}else{'Right.Name'}}
@{ Name = If($null -eq $Right){'Left.Name'}else{'Right.Name'}}
```

but every conditional statement I've tried either always evaluates true or always evaluates false.

Obviously, I'm missing something. How do I do this?

Begin edit:

```
$objectA = @(
@{
"Id"="1"
"Name"="Bob"
}, 
@{
"Id"="2"
"Name"="Bill"
},
@{
"Id"="3"
"Name"="Ted"
}
) 


$objectB = @(
@{
"Id"="2"
"Name"="John"
}
) 

$objectA | leftjoin $objectB -On Id -Property @{ID = 'Left.ID'}, @{Name = If($Right -ne $null){'Left.Name'}else{'Right.Name'}}|Format-Table
```

I want the output to look like:

```
ID Name
-- ----
1  Bob    
2  John
3  Ted
```

Comment: You need to share a reproducible example of the issue instead of having folks guessing but clearly `Name` should be just `Name='Name'` then the evaluation goes in the `Expression` scriptblock which is what you're currently missing.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what `leftjoin` is but assuming it works similarly to calculated properties for `Select-Object` this does the trick:

```bash
$objectA = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Id'   = '1'
        'Name' = 'Bob'
    },
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Id'   = '2'
        'Name' = 'Bill'
    },
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Id'   = '3'
        'Name' = 'Ted'
    }
)

$objectB = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Id'   = '2'
        'Name' = 'John'
    }
)

# assuming `$objectB` is an array of mutliple objects
# you will want a hashtable here for fast lookups,
# `Group-Object -AsHashtable` is an easy and efficient way to create one
$objectBMap = $objectB | Group-Object Id -AsHashTable -AsString
$objectA | Select-Object @(
    'Id'
    @{ 
        Name       = 'Name'
        Expression = {
            # if the Id from left exists in the right
            if ($objectBMap.ContainsKey($_.Id)) {
                # use the Name from the right
                return $objectBMap[$_.Id].Name
            }
            # else, use the Name from the left
            $_.Name
        }
    })
```

Comment: This is a useful workaround but I have found (and posted) the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the objects $Right and $Left are not exposed unless they are in a script block so the way to get the desired output in my example is:

```
$objectA = @(
@{
"Id"="1"
"Name"="Bob"
}, 
@{
"Id"="2"
"Name"="Bill"
},
@{
"Id"="3"
"Name"="Ted"
}
) 


$objectB = @(
@{
"Id"="2"
"Name"="John"
}
) 

$objectA | leftjoin $objectB -On Id -Property @{ID = 'Left.ID'}, @{Name = {if($Right['Name'] -ne $null){$Right['Name']}else{$Left['Name']}}}|Format-Table
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).